# Why and how Dirac cones are "tilted"?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, graphene, weyl-semimetal

Given a Weyl Hamiltonian, at rest,

$$ H = \vec \sigma \cdot \vec{p} ,$$

A Lorentz boost in the $x$ direction returns $ H = \vec\sigma\cdot\vec {p} - \gamma\sigma_0 p_x$.

The second term gives rise to a tilt in the "light" cone of graphene. My doubts are:

How  I  can derive such term given a  Lorentz transformations  in x direction? If the cone of "light" is "tilted" then the  Fermi velocity has changed?

[image]

Reference: Tilted anisotropic Dirac cones in quinoid-type graphene and α−(BEDT-TTF)2I3. M.O. Goerbig et al. [*Phys. Rev. B* **78**, 045415 (2008)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.78.045415), [arXiv:0803.0912](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0912).

Answer (score 1):

The Dirac cone in solids is emergent. Since the Dirac theory in solids is mounted on a lattice, depending on the connectivity of lattice (hopping pattern) and geometry of the lattice (some non-symmorphic lattices), the tilt can be introduced. 
In certain two-dimensional lattices, the perpendicular electric field (displacement field) can couple to the tilt and tune it. So in principle the tilt can be controlled (see Ref. 1 below).

Moreover, once the tilt is there, it can be neatly described by a metric. This metric will be a deformation of Minkowski metric which has interesting consequences for solids. For more details, please see:

1. Electric field assisted amplification of magnetic fields in tilted Dirac cone systems. S.A. Jafari, [*Phys. Rev. B* **100**, 045144 (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.100.045144), [arXiv:1904.01328](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.01328).
2. Polarization tensor for tilted Dirac fermion materials: Covariance in deformed Minkowski spacetime. Z. Jalali-Mola and S.A. Jafari, [*Phys. Rev. B* **100**, 075113 (2019)](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevB.100.075113), [arXiv:1904.13277](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.13277).
3. Electrodynamics of tilted Dirac/Weyl materials: A unique platform for unusual surface plasmon polaritons. Z. Jalali-Mola, S.A. Jafari, [arXiv:1908.07082](https://arxiv.org/abs/1908.07082) (2019).

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange! Please see [these guidelines](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11400) for how to reference papers, and [these guidelines for how to cite your own work](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/582/how-do-you-cite-yourself). There's nothing wrong with the latter but it needs to be suitably disclosed.